# How would I form a correct POST request to LinkedIn to exchange the temp auth code for the access token and is SSL3 the cause?

Tags: javascript, post, linkedin-api

I'm still a bit confused about how to form the correct POST request to LinkedIn to exchange the already received temporary authorization code for the user's access token as described in the LinkedIn docs at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication in step 3b.

There it says a **POST** request should be made, but instead of the POST request format, the docs give this URL with query parameters:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code
                                       &code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
                                       &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
                                       &client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
                                       &client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

I'm using server-side JavaScript and would like to form the proper POST request. Does this look correct?

```
r = 'POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1' + crlf;
r += 'Host: www.linkedin.com' + crlf + crlf;
r += parameters;
```

Where crlf is '\r\n' and parameters would be in the body and would be:

```
grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY&client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

with the upper-case values being replaced by the actual values for our app and the user.

Then the request itself would be sent to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken using a function I have for making HTTP requests.

Does that seem correct? Is that sufficient for forming a proper POST request?

Must I also include Referer, Content-Type and Content-Length headers? If so, should my request actually look like this?

```
        r = 'POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1' + crlf;
        r += 'Host: www.linkedin.com' + crlf ;
        r += 'Referer: http://' + site.txMainServer + '/LinkedProfile' + crlf;
        r += 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' + crlf;
        r += 'Content-Length: ' + parameters.length + crlf + crlf;
        r += parameters;
```

Where site.txMainServer is the server's URL.

**New info:** If I try the above code, rather than returning JSON with the access token, the following error is returned when I make my POST request: "* Connection error: 1590".

**New info 2:** Somebody told me that LinkedIn would also accept a GET request. So instead of a POST I tried a GET request in the exact form of the URL shown above in the LinkedIn documentation. But I also get a "* Connection error: 1590" if I try that. So I am stuck.

**New info 3:** Since it is an HTTPS request I tried replacing the Host header above with

```
Host: www.linkedin.com:443
```

but that didn't help. I still get the same "* Connection error: 1590".

**New info 4:** I believe the 1590 error is a "failure to make an SSL connection" error from **my** server. I have since tested by making successful SSL POST requests from my server to other SSL sites with the **exact same headers and parameters** (adjusting the Host of course to match the other server) for testing and have returned successful replies. So there is something about the LinkedIn server that is different. It wants *some different format* of a POST request, but I don't know what it is.

**New Info 5:** It appears our server is trying to make a POST request via SSL3 to exchange the temporary authentication code for the access token needed to make API calls, but we are experiencing handshake failures. Is SSL3 not supported at all for the LinkedIn API now?

It's just not clear to me why, if LinkedIn docs say they want a **POST** they instead give an example showing a full URL with query parameters, rather than the exact format of the POST request they want.

It appears I am not doing it the way LinkedIn wants, and would appreciate any assistance here. If I could just see an example of the correct format of the POST request I'm sure I can proceed from there! But it's not in the LinkedIn docs.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with server-side js (you mean nodejs?).

so shot in the dark: some companies require params both in the `URL` & POST `body` and linkedin require `HTTPS` request, maybe `www.linkedin.com` is not right.

PS. can't edit comments,just post here;(

Comment: Thanks for dropping by. This server-side js is not in widespread use, though it has been around a long time - Webcrossing. There's an httpReq() function which lets you make GET requests or you can make a complete POST request including all the headers, which is what I'm trying to do. If the headers are what LinkedIn wants it should work. The problem is I am not sure what headers they want exactly, because their docs don't explicitly show an example. In addition to the body, you think I should also try making the request itself with all the parameters? Or that the Host header is not right?

Comment: @DougLerner Is there any `httpsReq()` function (I mean function which use `HTTPS` protocal).

Comment: There is not a separate httpsReq() function. That should not be needed because the first parameter is a fully specified URL including protocol, so a request to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken should ok with this function. I will double-check to be sure though. Thanks.

Comment: I did confirm that httpReq() also works when making calls to URLS with the https:// protocol. So it's something else.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I found the answer. At https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth2-api-not-working-all-sudden LinkedIn employees post the following in response to people having problems which seem much like mine:

"In light of the recent disclosure of the "Poodle" SSL vulnerability, LinkedIn
is joining the large number of services that have actively removed support for
SSLv3, effective immediately. If you are experiencing errors related to
HTTPS-based communication with our APIs, please ensure you are using a
client/library that supports TLS 1.0+ instead of SSLv3 to avoid disruption.""

and

"There is no fix for this issue. It is the result of an unfixable vulnerability
in the SSLv3 protocol itself, which is well outside of LinkedIn's control. We
will not be re-enabling support for this. You will have to use a library that
can make a different SSL connection."

It appears we have to upgrade our SSL or cannot proceed.

doug

Comment: I am curious though why GET is working fine at LinkedIn with SSL3 and only POST is having a problem.